How to implement Model View Presenter in Android Java?
// Presenter interface
public interface MainPresenter {
    void loadData();
}

// View interface
public interface MainView {
    void showData(String data);
    void showError(String message);
}

// Model class
public class DataModel {
    public String getData() {
        return "Sample Data";
    }
}

// Concrete Presenter implementation
public class MainPresenterImpl implements MainPresenter {
    private MainView view;
    private DataModel model;

    public MainPresenterImpl(MainView view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = new DataModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void loadData() {
        String data = model.getData();
        if (data != null) {
            view.showData(data);
        } else {
            view.showError("No data available");
        }
    }
}

// Activity implementing the View
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView {
    private MainPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        presenter = new MainPresenterImpl(this);
        presenter.loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public void showData(String data) {
        // Display data on the screen
    }

    @Override
    public void showError(String message) {
        // Show error message
    }
}


How should the Presenter interact with the View in Java?
What’s the best way to update the View when data in the Model changes?
Should the Presenter hold a reference to the View or should the View communicate with the Presenter?
I expected the MainActivity to display the data provided by the DataModel, but I’m not seeing the data update properly in the view.
